# Convergence of subsequences resulting in the convergence of the original sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence of real numbers $\{s_n\}$ has subsequences $\{s_{3n}\}$ , $\{s_{3n-1}\}$ , 
and $\{s_{3n-2}\}$ all converging to the same real number, why must the original sequence $\{s_n\}$ converge?

Comment: Every integer can be written in the form $3n, 3n-1$ or $3n-2$

Comment: Can this serve as a real proof for this problem?

Comment: You going to have to fill in some details....people will not usually do the problem for you, but rather point you in the right direction.

Comment: But I am having trouble filling the details in this problem......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each of the three sub-sequences converges (to $L$), then

$\forall \epsilon, \exists N_1, N_2, N_3$ such that

$3n \ge N_1, |s_{3n} - L|$ and

$3n-1 \ge N_2 , |s_{3n-1} - L |$ and

$3n-2 \ge N_3, |s_{3n-2} - L |$

If we let $N = max\{N_1, N_2, N_3\}$, then

$\forall n \ge N$ the distance between $s_n$ and $L$ is less than epsilon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can the same proof work if we change the problem to say the convergence of S(3n) and say S(3n-1) only, that is drop one of the conditions?